# Select Max Value for Row Variable based on Two Conditions

Tags: r

I am trying to display the maximum group (Activity Group) based on a numeric value (Count) for each location (Location)

```
| Location     | Activity Group | Count |
| Location A   | Theft          | 12    |
| Location A   | Arson          | 15    |
| Location A   | Alcohol        | 8     |
| Location B   | Theft          | 22    |
| Location B   | Arson          | 19    |
| Location C   | Theft          | 10    |
| Location C   | Arson          | 18    |
| Location C   | Alcohol        | 30    |
| Location C   | Drugs          | 28    |
```

My desired output table looks like:

```
| Location     | Activity Group | Count |
| Location A   | Arson          | 15    |
| Location B   | Theft          | 22    |
| Location C   | Alcohol        | 30    |
```

Basically, I want the Activity Group value (Count) to determine the maximum value for each Activity Group at a Location.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Use `slice_max` i.e. `df1 %>% group_by(Location) %>% slice_max(n = 1, order_by = Count)`

Comment: Great, thank you!